# How do I add to the Datepicker from antd datamask from imask

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make it so that when entering 12012003 , it changes to 12.01.2003. Is it possible?

```
   <DatePicker
        onChange={(event) =\> {
          let value = null; 
          const isDate = event?.hasOwnProperty('$D');
          if (isDate) {
            value = event;
          }          
        onChange(value, null, name);
        }}
        placeholder="Выбрать дату"
        format="DD.MM.YYYY"
        {...baseProps}
   />
```

I have searched for a solution on various forums but without success . Most likely due to the fact that this Datepicker uses its own ipnut nothing and does not work.